# if time complexity vector.size() is o(1) then why we save the its size in variable

Tags: c++, stl

if time complexity vector. size() is o(1) then why do we save its size in another variable and use it to create a loop

```
vector<int>v={5,9,5,4,6,2,48};
int n=v.size();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
```

why don't we prefer this as shown bellow

```
vector<int>v={5,9,5,4,6,2,48};
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
```

I am trying to know the reason behind this

Comment: Do we? Really??

Comment: It might be because`v.size()` is changing in the loop.  Then, your two examples exhibit different behaviour.Where is this code taken from?

Comment: Sure, it's O(1) but retrieving the size might still involve a function call and possibly even a calculation depending on the compiler optimization level and the underlying implementation.  It doesn't hurt to store the result in a variable.  Although for a loop over 7 elements, I'd say such concerns are a bit misplaced.

Comment: 1) `int n = v.size();` is an antipattern. If certain compiler warnings are enabled, this code won't even compile. Hints: type size, type signed-ness. 2) Please read tag descriptions before you use tags.

Comment: Not sure who you mean by "we". I for one would likely write `for (int elem : v)` (unless access to the index is important for something, e.g. walking two vectors in parallel).